# can't install mbtiles plugin in geoserver

Tags: tomcat7, openlayers-3, geoserver, mbtiles

I am trying to install mbtiles plugin for geoserver 2.9. I have successfully installed geoserver in tomcat 7.0 (in windows 10).

I downloaded geoserver from [http://ares.opengeo.org/geoserver/master/] It works fine without any plugin installed.

But when I try to install plugin mbtiles into the lib folder it gives me error message.

```
HTTP Status 404 - /geoserver    
type Status report    
message /geoserver    
description The requested resource is not available.    
Apache Tomcat/7.0.59
```

I know my tomcat is working fine and geoserver is there in the webapps folder.

I downloaded the mbtiles plugin from: [http://ares.opengeo.org/geoserver/master/community-2015-11-30/]. I know that my version of mbtiles plugin and geoserver is same. That is what was mentioned in geoserver documentation page.

I have 3 files in the mbtiles plugin:

```
gs-mbtiles-2.9-SNAPSHOT.jar
gt-mbtiles-15-SNAPSHOT.jar
sqlite-jdbc-3.8.6.jar
```

If I remove those files from lib folder then my geoserver works fine.

Can anyone suggest what am I missing here??

I tried with other versions of geoserver but I get the same error message like above.

Any help is appreciated.

Cheers

Comment: what does the log file say?

Comment: Have you found a solultion? I'm encountering the same problem..

Comment: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'mbtilesProcess' defined in URL [jar:file:/C:/Users/Me/Documents/apache-tomcat-7.0.68-windows-x64/apache-tomcat-7.0.68/webapps/geoserver/WEB-INF/lib/gs-mbtiles-2.8-SNAPSHOT.jar!/applicationContext.xml]: Cannot resolve reference to bean 'wpsResourceManager' while setting constructor argument; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No bean named 'wpsResourceManager' is defined. - @iant

Answer (score 2):

I had this problem for a while. At first look at log file which is in this directory `\logs\wrapper.log` it shows the errors and why they prevent running geoserver's service. 
One of dependencies which `mbtile` plug-in has is `wps` plug-in. This plug-in is not loaded into `geoserver` by default. So before installing `mbtiles` plug-in at first install `geoserver wps` plug-in from this link

[Select and download wps](http://geoserver.org/release/stable/)

Another thing that I have fount is that some times `sqlite-jdbc-3.8.6.jar` which is in mbtile's zip file has a bug.It is quite an old version. So if your problem exists replace this file with newest version from here
[sqlite-jdbc download link](https://bitbucket.org/xerial/sqlite-jdbc/downloads)

I hope this helps some one. If yes please vote it up.

Answer (score -2):

You have to put it on:

```
/usr/share/opengeo/geoexplorer/WEB-INF/lib
```

Source: http://suite.opengeo.org/docs/latest/intro/installation/redhat/postinstall.html

Well, since opengeo-geoserver is a custom build from geoserver, it has some modifications that won't let you simply run the original geoserver plugins. 
You'll have to open the jars and decompile the class files to modify the code of the plugin to match the structure of opengeo-geoserver...